# function php for redirecting to homepage gives an infinite loop

Tags: php, loops, header, location, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect all sub-pages that may be called to the main page (some of the old links are still on google), and the pages don't exist anymore.

So I made a function in PHP, I call it in my index.php at the top, but Firefox and Chrome detect an infinite loop.

I don't know what's wrong with it.

Here is my function:

```
<?php 
  function homepage() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.html' 
    || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/home.html' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/default.html') {
      header('location:http://www.website.com', true, 301);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? as if you're calling this on every page visit, chrome will detect this as an infinate loop as it's always being encountered, maybe not always redirecting but always entering this loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the page on http://www.website.com, won't that be an index.php, So what you're doing will be sending it to http://www.website.com/index.php with the redirect and then checking again and sending it to http://www.website.com/index.php and then checking again and sending it to http://www.website.com/index.php and then checking again and sending it to http://www.website.com/index.php and then checking again and sending it to http://www.website.com/index.php and then checking again and sending it to http://www.website.com/index.php

Comment: add `if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] !== "www.website.com"){ //rest of redirect code}

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
function homepage(){

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/index.php' and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/index.html' 
                and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/home.html' and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/default.html'){
            header('location:http://www.website.com', true, 301);
        }
    }
?>
```

Now, that should make it right :)

Comment: that's exactly what I don't want to do

Comment: What yuu do in your function is to send the pages you specify to the firstpage. If this is what you want then that to do its correct. Not taking the loop into concideration. However. My changes makes all pages apart from those indexpages that might have existed to the firstpage. You said "I need to redirect all sub-pages that may be called to the main page .". That can include other pages than old firspages? In general, i would recommend doing this redirect in htaccess or similar.